# size of list<webelement> increases after for iteration

Tags: java, selenium

I have a problem with my code, 
the size of my list increases after for iteration :

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//b[@ng-click='column.visible=!column.visible;']")
List<WebElement> columnsNotChecked;
int i = 0 ;
    this.waitElementToBeClickable(columns);
    columns.click();
    System.out.println("Value : " + columnsNotChecked.size());
    for (WebElement webElement : columnsNotChecked) {
        if (i!=7) {
            webElement.click();
        }
        System.out.println(i);
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println("Value : " + columnsNotChecked.size());
```

This is the output : 
Value : 13,
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12,
Value : 21

can somebody help me please ?

Comment: What does `webElement.click()` do? Does it add elements to `columnsNotChecked`?

Comment: webelement.click() checks the box

Comment: try checking the box and see if in actual the columns not checked list increases and if there is a pattern to it. adjust your code in same way. Else if you only want those 13 elements to work, possible find another locator which does not increase.

Comment: Try printing `columnsNotChecked.size()` inside the loop. It'll give you a better sense of the behavior

Comment: @GalAbra after the fourth iteration the size changes to 21

Comment: Well, it's up to the webpage's behavior...

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
List<WebElement> columnsNotChecked = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//b[@ng-click='column.visible=!column.visible;']"));  
System.out.println("This is the size of list:"+columnsNotChecked.size());  
this.waitElementToBeClickable(columns);
columns.click();  
int i =0 ;

for(WebElement webElement :columnsNotChecked){
if(i!=7){
webElement.click();
}
System.out.println(i);
        i++;
}

 System.out.println("Value : " + columnsNotChecked.size());
```